# Count system calls for processes in Minix 3 and print processes/#of sys calls with F8

Tags: system-calls, minix

I need a way to count how many system calls every process uses (user, system, etc) and then print the results for all processes with `F8`. I'm guessing that I need to change `proc.c` and `proc.h` to add a process field and change `keyboard.c` to make the `F8` button print everything.

Any help with how to approach with would be greatly appreciated.